# Was the treaded submarine from *Le Manitoba ne répond plus* fictional in Hergés' time?

Tags: comics, history-of, bandes-dessinees, adventures-of-jo-zette-and-jocko

In *Le Manitoba ne répond plus*, the third story in Hergé's series *The Adventures of Jo, Zette and Jocko*, there is a submarine-like vehicle. It is pill-shaped, with glass portals and appears to be capable of going underwater much like a submarine, but it has treads like a bulldozer, suggesting that it drives along the bottom of the ocean.

During Hergé's time, were there any devices of this kind, or was this an entirely fictional machine?

Comment: Because all the other technology in Tintin is real, you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're only allowed to ask one question in a question here. Otherwise the OP could have put in a list of devices and asked how real they were...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submarine vehicles rolling on threads at the bottom of the ocean have been a recurrent theme in several major countries in the 20th century, with many projects and prototypes. Only a german armed tank Seeteufel (Seadevil) is apparently known to have been built, and possibly Soviet ones. Various such vehicles have been built for pacific purposes, repair and exploration.

source: http://modelscale.free.fr/histoire/SubtankUS_P/index.html

It is written in French, very well illustrated, including pictures of working vehicles and SciFi  designs.